# Unable to connect to the dependency-check database with jenkins or maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, owasp

When I run a clean install with Maven I get this error :

```
...   
  [DependencyCheck] [INFO] Processing Complete for NVD CVE - 2019  (11020 ms)
  [DependencyCheck] [INFO] Processing Complete for NVD CVE - 2017  (28415 ms)
  [DependencyCheck] [INFO] Processing Complete for NVD CVE - 2018  (16658 ms)
  [DependencyCheck] [INFO] Download Started for NVD CVE - Modified
  [DependencyCheck] [INFO] Download Complete for NVD CVE - Modified  (854 ms)
  [DependencyCheck] [INFO] Processing Started for NVD CVE - Modified
  [DependencyCheck] [INFO] Processing Complete for NVD CVE - Modified  (7572 ms)
  [DependencyCheck] [INFO] Begin database maintenance
  [DependencyCheck] [INFO] End database maintenance (41820 ms)
  [DependencyCheck] [INFO] Skipping RetireJS update since last update was within 24 hours.
  [DependencyCheck] [INFO] Begin database defrag
  [DependencyCheck] [INFO] End database defrag (9641 ms)
  [DependencyCheck] [INFO] Check for updates complete (205910 ms)
  [DependencyCheck] [ERROR] One or more fatal errors occurred
  [DependencyCheck] [ERROR] Unable to connect to the dependency-check database
```

Here is my pom.xml configuration for the dependency-check plugin for maven

```
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
        <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

I got the same problem with the dependency check plugin for Jenkins.

I have already tried to delete the `org/owasp/dependency-check-data` folder in my local repository but still have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I find a workaround for it

Copy the `odc.mv.db` file located in `org/owasp/dependency-check-data` in your maven project for example.

And change your plugin configuration like that

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
      <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <connectionString>jdbc:h2:file:/path-of/your/project/odc</connectionString>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

It should work